# Pandas query after groupby and agg function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following piece of code already, basically I'm grouping by week and then by the tenant, then manupulating the data by calculating the p95 and p90, now I only want to print violators, as in when p90 is >10 or p95 is > 50. I tried using query after manupulating the data frame, it doesn't work as it complains about key error. Any way I can run my computations inside the agg function itself ? Below is the code I have come up with :

```
total_logs_percentiles = data.groupby(['version_week', 'tenant']).agg({'time_in_queue': {'p90': p90_agg, 'p95': p95_agg},
                                                                       'duration': {'p90': p90_agg, 'p95': p95_agg}})
```

This is an example data output from the above expression:

```
                        time_in_queue  duration
                        p90      p95   p90  p95
version_week tenant
1            google      0.9     22   44    0.5
             yahoo       12      21   4     0.5
             bing        0.5     22   5     0.5
             duckduckgo  0.7     23   4     0.5
             IE          25      24   46    0.5
             Edge        60      25   47    0.5
```

Then I'm doing a query to filter the violators like below, but it doesn't work and complains with key error, how do I fix it ?

```
total_access_logs_percentiles.query('time_in_queue.p90 > 10', engine='python')
```

How do I fix the above and also optimizze this in such way that I can filter the values out in the agg function itself ? p90_agg and p95_agg are functions I already have.

Comment: It would be useful to provide a minimal example of the input and of the expected output

Comment: I guess you can use pd.loc instead of query. however you didn't provide any example of the data.

Comment: @mozway  Added example data

Comment: @DeanTaler added the example data